# What are the things which reduces (Android) battery time?

Tags: android, gps, wifi, power-management, battery

In one of our application we need to use the `GPS continuesly` ,the purpose is to get the user driving speed. Recently I found that while using the GPS continuesly can drain the device battery. 
If the GPS device is not used, device battery will work for hours but if the GPS is used it reduces the battery life dramatically.

1. I was wondering that "what are other things" which can reduce the battery time?
2. How we can avoid them ?
3. What are the best practices to use them?

Comment: Screen, wifi, blootooth,

Comment: The screen is what uses more battery, but you can't turn it off :) so maybe you can lower the bright, anything that runs on the device consumes battery, so you need to explain what are you using so we can help..

Comment: GPS and some nav apps are kiling battery at 1-2 hours.Make Full Cycle Charge when battery is under %20, use Battery Doctor

Comment: May i know the reason for -1, so i can avoid it next time?

Comment: A minor improvement, but I like to keep this in mind: You can't turn the screen off, but to reduce the power consumption on OLED displays you can use a dark/blackish layout. The darker the color of many pixels is, the less current the display uses. Not sure if this is one of the design decisions behind option menus going for a black/darkgrey since 2.3., but it might be. There is also a [color dependency](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2010/07/01/android-surfaceflinger-tricks-for-fun-and-profit/). Won't help on LCD devices though.

Comment: @YaqubAhmad your question is very vague.. like, everything drains battery. That's why you got -1.

Comment: @NeTeInStEiN: Thanks but let me explain why i am asking this question? If you do not use the GPS your device battery will work for hours but if you use the GPS its dramatically reduces the battery life. So that's the difference between "Every thing" & GPS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well i found the answer here, [Google I/O 2009 - Coding for Life -- Battery Life, That Is](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUemfrKe65c&feature=player_embedded)

[What can I do to increase battery life on my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/476/what-can-i-do-to-increase-battery-life-on-my-android-device)

Answer (score 3):

Wifi, Facebook Client, Application which runs lot of services in background. Gaming apps may drain your battery.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that is CPU intense. Each cpu cycle drains more battery life. So programs that run in the background, or anything that needs constant updating (GPS) are going to drain battery life.